# junit to check a method returning list

Tags: junit4, easymock

Need to write junit to check the following method which returns a list of files.

```
     public List<pdffiles> noticesPerform (Account account, fromDate, ToDate)
       {
         List<pdffiles> notices = new Arraylist();
            ............
            ..
         return notices;
       }
```

how to check in junit

1. how to check the return list is not null? whether need to use asserThat or something? Is there any best way to do it?
2. how to pass the test object account,fromDate,Todate to test the method?

Answer (score 0):

Use AssertNull() method to check for nulls.
Create the objects, or mock them (If you decide to take the mocking approach, you can create methods that initialize these parameter objects, then you can mock these objects by providing an alternative method for their creation.)

Answer (score 0):

use [fest assert 2.0](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki/Using-fest-assertions)
then you can do sth like:

```
XXX returnedList = noticesPerform (...)
assertThat(returnedList).containsOnly(A, B, C);
```